# How do I update the variables changed in a for loop?

Tags: java

I'm an AP computer science student and here is the assignment
Program Description:  You just started working as a programmer.  You've agreed to the following compensation package.

•   You are paid $30 an hour.
•   You earn an extra $25.50 an hour for any part of a day where you work more than 8 hours.
•   You earn an extra $15 an hour for hours beyond 40 in any one week.
•   You also earn a 125% bonus on any amount you earn for working on Saturday, and a 50% bonus for working Sunday.

Work hours that I used , stored as txt for file reader

```
9 8 10 8 9 9 5   
7 8 8 8 0 8 9   
6 10 5 0 0 0 0   
8 8 8 8 8 8 8   
6 6 6 6 6 6 6  
10 3 4 5 7 5 4  
8 8 8 8 8 0 0
```

Sample Output: (be sure to run several test cases of your own by adding additional data to your data file)

```
Hours Worked: 9 8 10 8 9 9 5        
Week # 1 $2581.88   
Hours Worked: 7 8 8 8 0 8 9    
Week # 2 $2033.25   
Hours Worked: 6 10 5 0 0 0 0  
Week # 3 $681   
Hours Worked: End of reading from file.   

Vs My output  
Total Hours Worked: 58

Week #1 $2010.00

Total Hours Worked: 48

Week #2 $1560.00

Total Hours Worked: 21

Week #3 $630.00

Total Hours Worked: 56

Week #4 $1920.00

Total Hours Worked: 42

Week #5 $1290.00

Total Hours Worked: 38

Week #6 $1140.00

Total Hours Worked: 40

Week #7 $1200.00

Hours Worked: End of reading from file.
```

The problem That I see is that what ever happens inside the for loops doesn't affect the outside of my code and I find that confusing.

Please don't change the entire code, I also want to understand the code at my current level so I can learn and progress, Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class wages {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inFile = null;
        int TotalW = 0; // total hours per week
        int TotalD = 0; // total hours per day
        double Wage = 0.0; // Wage for the weekdays
        double WageS = 0.0; // wage for sat
        double WageSu = 0.0; // wage for Sundays
        double Total = Wage + WageS + WageSu;
        int week = 1; // week # counter
        DecimalFormat TD = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); // formatter
        try {
            // Create a scanner to read the file, file name is parameter
            inFile = new Scanner(new File("Prog213a.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            // Stop program if no file found
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while (inFile.hasNext()) // as long as there is a next variable...
        {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) // count the week days / first 5 variables
            {
                TotalD = inFile.nextInt();
                if (TotalD > 8) Wage = Wage + ((TotalD - 8) * 25.50); // bonus if worked above 8 hours per day

                TotalW = TotalW + TotalD;
            }
            for (int x = 1; x <= 1; x++) {
                TotalD = inFile.nextInt();
                if (TotalD > 8) WageS = WageS + ((TotalD - 8) * 25.50);
                WageS = WageS + (WageS * 2.25);
                TotalW = TotalW + TotalD;
            }

            for (int x = 1; x <= 1; x++) {
                TotalD = inFile.nextInt();
                if (TotalD > 8) WageSu = WageSu + ((TotalD - 8) * 25.50);
                WageSu = WageSu + (WageSu * 2);
                TotalW = TotalW + TotalD;

            }

            if (TotalW > 40) Total = Total + ((TotalW - 40) * 15);


            Total = Total + (TotalW * 30);
            System.out.println("Total Hours Worked: " + TotalW);
            System.out.println("Week #" + (week++) + " $" + TD.format(Total));

            TotalW = 0;
            TotalD = 0;
            Wage = 0;
            WageS = 0;
            WageSu = 0;
            Total = Wage + WageS + WageSu;
        }
        System.out.println("Hours Worked: End of reading from file. ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about scopes. Start here: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: I sure would thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem, you may have a scope issue.

Any variables declared inside of a scope (anything inside curly braces) only lasts for as long as you are in that scope.

In your case, your scope is the for loop.

For instance.

```
(for int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    int y = y+x;
}
```

Your y value here would be inaccessible outside of the for loop.

However,

if you did:

```
int y = 0;
(for int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    y = y+x;
}
```

Your y value would be saved and usable elsewhere since it was declared outside of the scope of the for loop.

I hope this answers your question.

I also see that your for loop conditions are x<=1 where you are declaring x=1.  This will cause your loop to only run once.  Maybe that's what you intended.  I am not sure.

Good luck.

Comment: This is a great explanation and exactly explains the error I had in other codes but this one I declared all my variables outside of the while loop.

Comment: Also I would recommend reading [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for example: `Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.`

Comment: I agree with @Frakcool.  This will help everyone read your code and be able to provide quicker answers.  In the future, this will help your coworkers collaborate and understand the code you are writing.

Comment: @Basam yes you have it: **ALL** your variables start with uppercase, they shouldn't `int TotalW = 0;` **->** `int totalW = 0;` this is a "standard", Classes' names should start with an uppercase while variable names should start with lowercase... Believe me, it will improve a lot your coding skills and it will make it easier to us to read it.

Comment: Opps...I thought that starting with an uppercase made it more clear. Thank you! @Frakcool

Comment: @Basam I copied wrong the relevant part from the link, it was it: `Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. `

Answer (score 0):

First, use your IDEs autoformat to properly format your code; easy to read code is easy to reason about.

Secondly, your for loops are like this:

```
              for(int x=1; x<=1; x++) {...}
```

Think about how many times the body of the loop will get executed.

Comment: It would be executed once?

Comment: @Basam exactly; what does that code within the for loop do? How many times should it run? *Why*?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos The first for loop is for the first 5 numbers in the list because The starting day is Monday, then after that 1 loop for Saturday and then 1 for Sunday then the next five should be in the first loop mon-fri